# Use of "repl.bat"

Tags: batch-file, replace

Am I correct in assuming that repl.bat will not work if I'm trying to do a search & replace for a pattern that can be 3-4 lines long?

Whenever I try to use a '/s', '/n', or anything to continue the pattern search onto the next line, it fails to find any pattern at all.

e.g.  SEARCHING FOR THE FOLLOWING PATTERN

```
    for i in range(60):
        try:
            if self.is_element_present(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[id=Navigation] ul[id=mainNav] a[href='/DataValues/']"): break
        except: pass
        time.sleep(1)
    else: self.fail("time out")
```

So when I try:  `type file.py | repl "\sfor i in range\(60\)\:" "cookie" file.py.new`

...to represent the first line, it will find the first line successfully.

However if I add a '\n' or '\s' to continue searching for the pattern past the first line:

```
** type file.py | repl "\sfor i in range\(60\)\:\stry" "cookie" file.py.new **
```

...it fails to find anything and no changes are made.  I've tried different combinations of \n and \s & the results are always the same.  Thanks ahead of time for your help!

Comment: Where does `repl.bat` come from?

Comment: My apologies (https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat).

Comment: Here is the [original REPL.BAT post](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3855), and here is the [earliest StackOverflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16735079/1012053)

Comment: REPL.BAT has been superseded by [JREPL.BAT](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the documentation more carefully. You need the `M` option to be able to match across multiple lines.

For example, given **test.txt**

```
red
+
blue
```

Then

```
type test.txt | repl "red\s*\+\s*blue" "purple" m
```

yields

```
purple
```

Comment: Yikes, I feel dumb.  That wasn't my whole issue, but once I got that added, I was able to figure out the rest.  Thanks man.

Comment: Is there any chance you might know how to get this same process to see double quotes in the search?  I've tried using ' \" ' and ' "" ' to no avail.

Comment: @RichieByrd - It's in the built in help doc: Option 1) use the hex escape sequence`\x22`. Option 2) use `\q` with the X option.

Comment: Sorry, I had meant to mention I tried using \q, but that didn't work.  However, \x22 appears to have done the trick.  Thanks again man.

Comment: @RichieByrd - `\q` works fine as long as you remember the `X` option. For your case, the trailing option string would be `MX`.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out after my last message and reading the documentation.  Again, thank you for your help!